# could you tell me why does this code crash?

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers, crash

So I'm curious of the reason the following code crashes.
Will appreciate help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class temp
{    
  public:

    temp(int i)
    {
        intPtr = new int(i);
    }

    ~temp()
    {
        delete intPtr;
    }

  private:
    int* intPtr;
};

void f (temp fInput)
{
    cout << "f called" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    temp x = 2;
    f(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ Ed S: I agree, however, sometimes what we determine to be a crash may be different than what he thinks is a crash.

Comment: @josephthomas: Yeah I figured as much, which is why I deleted my comment shortly after posting it :)  We can agree on the correct use of the term... whether or not most beginners will use it correctly is another issue

Comment: You need to manage memory correctly if you use `new`. Or you could just not use `new` and have an integer instead of a pointer to an integer.

Answer (score 5):

The pointer is copied when x is passed (implicit copy constructor) and the destructor is called twice (before the function returns and before main returns), thus the memory is deleted twice.

Use `std::shared_ptr<int>` here instead instead of a raw int pointer (assuming you want the behavior to be the same, i.e. reference the same `int` from both `temp`s; otherwise, implement the copy constructor, move constructor and assignment operator yourself).

```
#include <memory>

class temp {    
public:
  temp(int i) : intPtr(std::make_shared<int>(i)) {

  }

private:
  std::shared_ptr<int> intPtr; // reference counting ftw
};
```

Comment: Or just correctly implement the class to begin with (i.e., correct copy semantics, etc.)

Comment: That's also possible, depending on the behavior you want.

Comment: OP didn't mention which behavior is "correct", so I can't magically know.

Comment: He doesn't need to.  Given the definition of the class it is incorrect to not provide a copy constructor and follow the rule of three.

Comment: With "behavior" I meant "copy the int or copy the pointer to the int?" With a shared_ptr you get the latter, and you can still assert the compiler generates a copy constructor for you.

Comment: But the compiler generating the copy constructor is exactly what is causing the problem.  As a consumer of this class you would need to know that instances of it simply cannot be passed by value and that they need to be wrapped by something like a `sahred_ptr`. Horrible, horrible, lazy design.

Comment: The shared_ptr would be a member of the class, instead of the raw int pointer. That's the point of the second paragraph of my answer. Consumers don't need to worry.

Comment: .....and that's what I get for skimming your response :).  I thought you were suggesting something completely different. Sorry, my misunderstanding.  +1 for being an annoying jerk :D

Answer (score 5):

The crash occurs because of the way you are passing `x`.

After the scope of the `f` function, `x`'s destructure will be called and will delete `intPtr`.

However, that will delete memory that is still in scope for `main`. Therefor, after `return 0` is called, it will try to delete memory that already exists as you are calling delete twice on the same pointer.

To fix this error, change

```
void f (temp fInput)
```

to

```
void f (const temp& fInput)
```

Alternatively, you could look into using a [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: Adding a copy constructor and assignment operator would be a good idea as well. You could also use std::shared_ptr instead of a raw pointer, as it take care of copy semantics.

Comment: I agree, I wanted to let the poster to know a solution that could help him in a minimal effort. There is many ways this crash can be solved.

Answer (score 5):

You are violating [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)

You maintain a pointer member and you pass a copy of the object to the function `f`.  So, the end result is that you call `delete` twice on the same pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're hitting here is a double delete.  Because you didn't define any copy constructors here C++ is happily doing so for you.  The implementation does this by performing a shallow copy of all of the contents.

```
f(x);
```

This line works by creating a copy of `x` and passing it to `f`.  At this point there are 2 `temp` instances which own a single `intPtr` member.  Both instances will delete that pointer and this is likely what is causing your crash.

To work around this you can take a number of steps

1. Use a pointer type meant for sharing like `shared_ptr<T>`
2. Create an uncallable copy constructor which forces the instance to be passed by ref

An example of #2 is

```
class temp {
  temp(const temp& other);
  temp& operator=(const temp& other);
public:
  // Same
};
```

Now the `f(x)` line simply won't compile because it can't access the necessary copy constructor.  It forces it to instead redefine `f` to prevent a copy.

```
void f(const temp& fInput) {
  ...
}
```